# How to prove that $\shortparallel T \shortparallel \leq \|T\|^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, operator-theory, orthogonality

**My question**. How to prove that  $\shortparallel T \shortparallel \leq \|T\|^{n}$ and, if $T$ is iniective, prove that $\|T^{-1}\|^{n}\leq \shortparallel T \shortparallel \leq \|T\|^{n}$?

First I need to state what I am using: I have two Hilbert spaces $V,W$ and $L:V\to W$ is a linear application between them. Then $\DeclareMathOperator{\dimn}{\operatorname{dim}} \DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{\operatorname{Sym}}$

1. if $\dimn V\leq \dimn W$ then exist $S\in \Sym (n)$ and $O\in O(V,W)$ such that $L=O\circ S$,
2. If $\dimn W\leq \dimn V$  then exist $S\in \Sym (n)$ and $O\in O(V,W)$ such that $L=S\circ O^{*}$,

where $O(V,W)$ is an orthogonal injective linear transformation and $\Sym(n)$ is a linear symmetric transformation.

In this case, when $L=O\circ S$ or $L=S\circ O^{*}$ then $\DeclareMathOperator{\Det}{\operatorname{Det}}$
$$ 
\shortparallel L \shortparallel\, \triangleq |\Det S|.
$$
**What I have tried**. Let $T\in L(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m})$ with $n\leq m$ and consider
$$
\|T\|=\sup \frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|},
$$
My idea is to use the following inequality
$$
\begin{split}
\|T\|^{n} & = \sup \frac{(\|T(x)\|)^{n}}{\|x\|^{n}} = \sup \frac{(\|O\circ S(x)\|)^{n}}{\|x\|^{n}} \\
& = \sup \frac{(\| S(x)\|)^{n}}{\|x\|^{n}}\geq \frac{\|S(x)\|^{n}}{\|x\|^{n}} = \frac{\|T^{*}\circ T (x)\|^{n}}{\|x\|^{n}},
\end{split}
$$
but how to continue? Maybe could I use the fact that
$$
(\det(T^{*}\circ T))^{\frac{1}{2}}= |\det S| =  \shortparallel T \shortparallel\;? $$
Please I need some help or any hint, thank you so much.

Comment: What's the difference between $\shortparallel T \shortparallel$ and $||T||$?

Comment: well, $||T||$ is a norm for one linear transformation, the other is obtain when you put polar decomposition for $T$  and take determinant of the simetriic part on that decompositon, i wrote that above, the professor dont say which norm $||.||$ to choose , thank you

Comment: why vote negative? just i want some hint or help please

Comment: That $S$ which is part of the polar decomposition : we have a formula $S = (T^*T)^{\frac 12}$ for it, right? And $\shortparallel T \shortparallel = |\det S|$ by definition of $\shortparallel \cdot \shortparallel$, right? Just verifying your background and my familiarity with the notation.

Comment: I guess both $V$ and $W$ are finitely-dimensional and $n=\dimn W$. Also If guess if $\dimn W<\dimn V$  then $O(V,W)$ is empty.

Comment: Would it be just straightforward from SVD that $\shortparallel T \shortparallel=\prod_{k=1}^n\sigma_k$ and $\|T\|=\sigma_{\max}$? It looks like an obvious claim.

Comment: thank you anyone, excusme i dont know what is SVD, but with your comment looks like easy to show that claim, thank you again

Comment: Teresa Lisbon , yes you right!

Comment: @weymarandres Thanks, then I can try the problem!

Comment: thanks to you Teresa Lisbon

Comment: It is [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it without *explicitly* using SVD, though, SVD is super useful, and you should definitely learn about it. Anyways, let $A$ be the matrix associated with $L$. By definition:

$$ \|L\|_2 = \|A\|_2 
= \sup_{x:x\neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}
= \max_{x: \|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|_2
= \max_{x: \|x\|^2 = 1} \|Ax\|_2^2
$$

The Lagrangian of this constrained optimization problem is $\mathcal L(x, \lambda) = \|Ax\|_2^2 - \lambda (\|x\|_2^2-1)$ which yields the first order condition

$$ 0=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathcal L(x, \lambda) = 2A^* Ax-2\lambda x \iff A^* A x=\lambda x $$

Thus the maximum is achieved for an eigenvector; in fact $\|A\|_2^2=\lambda_{\max}(A^* A)$. On the other hand you have already seen that $\shortparallel T \shortparallel^2 = \det(T^* T) = \prod_k \lambda_k(T^* T)$,  then$^{(*)}$, since all eigenvalues of $T^* T$ are positive it follows that

$$
\shortparallel T \shortparallel^2 = \prod_k \lambda_{k=1}^n(T^* T) \le \prod_{k=1}^n \lambda_{\max}(T^* T) =\lambda_{\max}(T^* T)^n =\|T\|_2^{2n}
$$

Note that by definition $\lambda_k (T*T) = \sigma_k(T)$ are exactly the singular values of $T$

$(*)$ if $\dim V <\dim W$, instead we have $\shortparallel T \shortparallel^2 = \det(TT^*)$ and the same argument holds

Comment: My feeling is that the optimization could be avoided here as the OP seems to (almost) arrive to the relation $\|T\|=\|S\|$ in his attempt. If you start here and assume that $\|S\|=|\lambda|_{\max}(S)$ is known then your final estimation for $|\det S|$ works as well.